# Refactor Regex Pattern - Java

Tags: java, regex

I have the following `aaaa_bb_cc` string to match and written a regex pattern like

`\\w{4}+\\_\\w{2}\\_\\w{2}` and it works. Is there any simple regex which can do this same ?

Comment: Yours is really simple, for a regular expression. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sometimes do what I call "meta-regexing" as follows:

```
    String pattern = "x{4}_x{2}_x{2}".replace("x", "[a-z]");
    System.out.println(pattern); // prints "[a-z]{4}_[a-z]{2}_[a-z]{2}"
```

Note that this doesn't use `\w`, which can match an underscore. That is, your original pattern would match `"__________"`.

If `x` really needs to be replaced with `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, then just do it in the one place (instead of 3 places).

#### Other examples

- [Regex for metamap in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728910/regex-for-metamap-in-java)
- [How do I convert CamelCase into human-readable names in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559759/how-do-i-convert-camelcase-into-human-readable-names-in-java)

Comment: @UK: Essentially the idea is that you don't need to have the actual regex explicitly written out. If it makes it more readable/maintainable to derive the regex programmatically, then go ahead

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to escape the underscores:

```
\w{4}+_\w{2}_\w{2}
```

And you can collapse the last two parts, if you don't capture them anyway:

```
\w{4}+(?:_\w{2}){2}
```

Doesn't get shorter, though.

(Note: Re-add the needed backslashes for Java's strings, if you like; I prefer to omit them while talking about regular expressions :))

Comment: Yes. I can understand that ;)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use just `\\w{4}_\\w{2}_\\w{2}` or maybe `\\w{4}(_\\w{2}){2}`.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your \w does not need to match underscore, so you can use `[a-zA-Z0-9]` instead

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}_[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}_[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}
```

Comment: Missed that one. However, is `\w` in Java really only `[a-zA-Z0-9]`? In .NET at least both `\d` and `\w` match pretty much anything counting as decimal number or letter.